Vue3's issue of the execution order of onLoad in different components
I have 2 comonents: A and B, each one has onLoad method.  B will be used by A.
There is a ref named 'key' in A which is valued in A.onLoad, then passed to B as a parameter. In onLoad method of B, key is used to get data from server, but B.onLoad is executed before A.onLoad, so the key is undefined.
My problem is: How to ensure that the key is initialized correctly by A before it is used in B.onload.

Don't do initialization in a lifecycle hook if it depends on a reactive value. Put a watcher on the prop to re-initialize the component every time the prop changes.

I usually prefer Moritz's solution, but maybe if the prop isn't expected to change then alternatively it might make sense to delay rendering/loading of B with a v-if, e.g. <B v-if="key"  :key="key"> which prevents rendering of B until key has a value.
